# Script runs fine online, but not in XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a very simple cookie script that functions perfectly online. but won't work in XAMPP. I've tried lots of things but with no luck. The snippet has all the code. I've tried many variants, but it simply won't work in XAMPP. I suspect that there's something in the configuration of XAMPP that I don't understand.

```js
if($('.cookie-banner').length){
    $('.cookie-banner').slideDown(1000);
}
```

```css
body {
    font:0.75em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   
}

a {
    color:slategray;
}

.cookie-banner {
    display:none;
    background: #B4B4B4;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:9999999;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -ms-filter: “alpha(opacity=80)”;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -khtml-opacity: .8;
    -moz-opacity: .8;
    color:#000000;
}

.cookie-banner .container {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 15px;
    height:auto;
}
```

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET['aawh_c'])) {
    $expire=time()+60*60*24*365;
    setcookie('aawh_c','true',$expire);
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Cookie Banner</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
   if (! isset($_COOKIE['aawh_c'])) {
    ?>
   <div Class="cookie-banner">
        <div class="container">
        <p>We use cookies on this website. By using this website, we'll assume you consent to <a href="/cookies">the cookies we set</a>.</p>
         <a href="?aawh_c" class="button">OK, continue</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
   }
   ?>
    <p> Lots of fantastic content here.</p>
   <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="global.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Won't work" isn't an error message or problem statement which we can use to diagnose or fix anything. In what way won't it work? Do you get a PHP error perhaps when you access it? Or some JS problem in the console? Is there some unexpected behaviour perhaps in one area? None of this is clear, and we cannot access your environment to run the code, or see your logs etc. Since you say it works in another environment, that usually means the code itself is not at fault. You'll need to do some digging and give us a meaningful problem report before we can be of any help. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't get any errors. The banner simply doesn't appear in XAMPP, but works fine online.

Comment: Well, looking at the PHP code, the banner is only supposed to appear if the relevant cookie is not set. Has the code which creates the cookie been executed? Did you debug that? You can also check in the browser's developer tools to see what cookies are set for the site (which presumably is `localhost`)

Comment: Yes, I have. Online the cookie gets set and the banner disappears as it should. Delete the cookie and it reappears. With XAMPP, the banner never appears so the cookie can't be set. However, if the banner is disabled, it's possible to set the cookie. Obviously, in those circumstances, the cookie does nothing.

Comment: And before anyone asks, I have PHP 7.4.33 both online and in XAMPP.

Comment: `header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);` - don't do that. Ever. This will simply fail for many clients that either completely block the sending of any referrer, or send a "fake" one, for privacy reasons.

Comment: _"However, if the banner is disabled, it's possible to set the cookie."_ - what exactly does "banner is disabled" mean?

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as CBroe - it's unclear what you mean by "disabled" in this context. Are you talking about disabling cookies in the browser or something? There's nothing specific in the code which would "disable" the banner, other than seting that cookie. It's also unclear what you mean by `With XAMPP, the banner never appears so the cookie can't be set`...in the code, the banner only appears when the cookie **isn't** set. Your statement therefore seems to be a contradiction. If you aren't seeing the banner, the most likely explanation is that the cookie is set.

Comment: Now we might be making progress... for comparison, I put your code into my own local PHP/Apache environment (also provided by XAMPP). It failed until I made sure the jquery-1.10.2.min.js file was present in the page (because the CSS hides the banner, and the jquery code is supposed to show it). Then it worked fine. Before that, there was an error in the browser's Console mentioning that $ is not defined (indicating that jQuery isn't present). Before you said there were no errors, but I think maybe that's not true. Check again in your browser's Console when you're loading the page.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. I checked and jquery-1.10.2.min.js is indeed being loaded, but didn't appear to be doing anything, exactly as you said. After some poking around. I found the problem and to say that I feel totally embarrassed is an understatement! It was being blocked by me add blocker (Adblock Plus)!!! With that disabled, it works fine.

Comment: For those that have asked what I mean by "disabled", I simply mean commenting out display:none; in the css.

Comment: No problem, glad you fixed it. It happens to us all! It's always the thing you're not expecting. You can probably delete the question because it has no particular value as a programming problem.

Comment: `I simply mean commenting out display:none; in the css`...that's fine but you should _always_ be specific and precise when describing changes to us, otherwise - as you see - we're unsure what's happening.

Comment: I thought I'd made most of the novice mistakes, but apparently not! Thanks again from a very red face.